# Selected language at the time of installation want to save after installation

Tags: c#, .net, inno-setup

I have an setup file which provide options to select the language, but I unable to understand the how can I save/keep the selected language that I can use after the installation.

Comment: You can access selected language either by expanding [`{language}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=language) constant or by [`ActiveLanguage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_activelanguage.htm) function. Where and how do you want to save it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code can get language during installation：

```
ResultLan := ExpandConstant('{language}');
```

and then you can use(ResultLan) after the installation.

Comment: It's easier to just call `ActiveLanguage` function. It [`internally expands`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/ScriptFunc_R.pas#L958) the `{language}` constant for you.